# ASP.NET Custom Model Binding: DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

***The problem***

At this point I have a problem where my Get action is trying to read a DateTime parameter in a diferent format that is sent.

While the DateTime sent has this format: `0:dd/MM/yyyy`
The Get Actions expects: `0:MM/dd/yyyy`

***The solution (maybe)***

In order to change what the Get action is expecting I'm using a Custom Model Binding.

**The GET Action**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, [ModelBinder(typeof(PModelBinder))]DateTime date)
```

**The ModelBinder class**

Now here are a few things that are missing and I don't know how to complete it properly:

```
public class PModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string theDate = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["date"]; 
        //What should I write inside the []? 
        //I've tried QueryString["date"] which is the name of the parameter but it says is wrong
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        bool success = DateTime.TryParse(date); //Should I apply ParseExact? How should I do it?
        if (success)
        {
            return new //what should I be returning here? dt?
        }

    }
}
```

I've several questions marked as comments in the code above since I'm just starting to understand Custom Model Binding. Hope anyone can give me some advice.

I'm following this article:

https://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization

But it's from **2008!!!**, Although it seems valid since it's exactly the problem I'm having with my GET Action (diferent date formats)

***Update: aditional information***

The parameter date is defined as:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaLInicioLiq { get; set; }
```

and the URL build when calling that GET Action has this structure for the date parameter:

```
date=10%2F11%2F2017%200%3A00%3A00
```

Comment: Alberto You need to DateTime  "0:MM/dd/yyyy" to "0:dd/MM/yyyy " .Am I correct ...

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM The datetime is sent with this format: 0:dd/MM/yyyy, but the GET Action is trying to read the parameter as if it's format were 0:MM/dd/yyyy, thus generating an error. So I need that the GET Actions starts accepting the 0:dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: Suggest your look at the code in [this article](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2016/12/28/custom-model-binders-asp-net-core/) for core-mvc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several issues with your model binder implementation:

1. Do not hardcode parameter name (`date`). Use `bindingContext.ModelName` instead.
2. You should handle situation if value was not actually provided. You could check it by comparing result of `IValueProvider.GetValue()` with `ValueProviderResult.None`.

Here is sample DateTime model binder that accomplish what you need:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IModelBinder baseBinder = new SimpleTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateTime));

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            //  valueAsString will have a string value of your date, e.g. '31/12/2017'
            var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(valueAsString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(dateTime);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return baseBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to implement it but I'm gettint an error claiming that the result of this line: bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProvideResult); once is passed to the ParseExact function, that string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I'm trying to debug it on that line to see the value but it skips that line and throw the error before I could see it.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/otBzAWe.png     It says that the result of SetModelValue, once is evaluated for the PArseExact function, is not considered a valid DateTime format ):

Comment: As far as your date string also contains time part (0:00:00) you should use following format for ParseExact(): DateTime.ParseExact(valueAsString, "dd/MM/yyyy h:m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying with 0:dd/MM/yyyy but it was not good enough. I don't think I would have dealt with this problem without your help! Thanks again!

Comment: working example but i would suggest nullable DateTime to return null if not binded