# MVC TextBoxFor type "date" is it possible to use custom format?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, input, datepicker, datetime-format

I have an issue/question, i would like to bind a model property of type DateTime to a TextBoxFor with type date, is it actually possible to use following format to display an existing date: **dd/MM/yyyy** ?

I have tried the following [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097748/date-does-not-display-from-model-on-html-input-type-date) but i only manage to display a date if it is in the **"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"** format. I am aware of the default format that is browser dependant, like an English browser will render mm/dd/yyyy and a Dutch one dd/mm/yyyy. How would one display an existing date  from the model to what type of control for the format dd/mm/yyyy?

I have tried setting this desired format in the Model with annotations, in my view and also in my controller but no success. I also tried with a EditorFor but this removes the DatePicker functionalities when i click it, in other words i don't have a datepicker anymore :) I also tried a TextBox(...) but same problem.

This is my View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Contract.EndDate, new { Value = @Model.Contract.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })
```

Can someone suggest me the best proper of doing this?
Kind regards!

Comment: It is possible. But using `new { Value = @Model.Contract.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), ... }` is not a proper way to do this. You can use `[DisplayFormat(DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy")]` for `DateTime` viewmodel property instead.

Comment: Agreed with @TetsuyaYamamoto. We can put DisplayFormat attribute within the ViewModel of your EndDate property

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, i tried that before (as suggested in the answer of Stephen Muecke but that doesn't work (i re tried it as well). I still have the same results. But when i change it to "mm/dd/yyyy" it works...

Comment: Sounds like `DefaultModelBinder` is messing up with date format for `DateTime` inputs. You can try creating custom model binder with specified format as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449015/asp-net-custom-model-binding-datetime) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356601/custom-datetime-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: Alright i will have a look at it and try it to see if i can make it work this way. I don't know DefaultModelBinder so i will do some research first :) Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: When you add `type="date"` it generates the browsers HTML5 datepicker, and the purpose of that is to display the date in the users culture, not your culture (if I navigate to the site I would see it in `dd/MM/yyyy` format (Australia) but a US user would see it in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. If you want a datepicker in a defined format, use a jQuery datepicker, not the HTML5 datepicker (which is not supported in many older browsers anyway). In addition, NEVER set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods.

Comment: Alrigth so i tried implementing a custom Binder but that didn't worked, maybe i didn't configure it properly, that is of course a possibility. However i agree with Stephen Muecke's explanation, if a HTML5 datepicker is not widely supported i don't want to use it and will try to use the Jquery datepicker. I will report my results back here, probably today. Would you like to elaborate why you should never set the value attribute with a HtmlHelper please Stephen? (thank you!)

Comment: @Dimitri. The HTML5 date picker is not supported as all in IE and only in the latest versions of FireFox (for about 6 mths I think). The `HtmlHelper` correctly generate the `value` by first using `ModelState`, then the `ViewDataDictionary` and finally the actual model value. Read the 2nd part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) to understand one of the problems with setting the `value` yourself

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you very much, as always, decent elaborated explanations! Great to have people doing what you do around here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we managed to get a JQuery to work in our current project, we had to reorder and structure already present javascript references but that was actually a great thing because we cleaned things up a bit :). We used the [JQuery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as suggested by [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) (thank you again for all provided information) and thank you as well [Tetsuya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto) because i didn't know anything about the DefaultModelBinder and now i know a little more :). Like always i learned something new, thank you!