# Custom DateTime ModelBinder is being bypassed in ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to create a HTTP GET Web API that only accepts dates in ISO-8601 format i.e. YYYY-MM-DD. I have the following simple API Controller that takes in the DateTime, and I am applying a custom model binder via an attribute:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApiDates.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WebApiDatesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("datetime")]
        public IActionResult GetDateTime([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(IsoDateModelBinder))] DateTime date)
        {
            return Ok($"Date was {date}");
        }
}
```

The custom model binder looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApiDates
{
    public class IsoDateModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private readonly IModelBinder _baseBinder;

        public IsoDateModelBinder(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _baseBinder = new SimpleTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateTime), loggerFactory);
        }

        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

                var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

                var dateTimeParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(valueAsString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTimeResult);
                if (dateTimeParsed)
                {
                    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(dateTimeResult);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }

            return _baseBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the project is a standard .NET 5.0 Web API project, created with `dotnet new webapi`.

To test this, I have the following unit test:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
using WebApiDates;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using System.Net;

namespace WebApiDates.Tests
{
    public class WebApiTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public WebApiTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("2021-08-21", HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [InlineData("2021-21-08", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("08-21-2021", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("21-08-2021", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("2021/08/21", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("2021/21/08", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("08/21/2021", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("21/08/2021", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("08.21.2021", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("21.08.2021", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("2021.08.21", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [InlineData("2021.21.08", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        public async Task DateTimeTests(string date, HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode)
        {
            // Arrange
            using var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/webapidates/datetime?date={date}");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(expectedStatusCode, response.StatusCode);
        }           
    }
}
```

The problem is that only the first test should return the `OK` result, whereas the following tests are also returning `OK`:

[image: Image of tests that should not be failing]

And when I debug the model binder, it is doing the date parsing correctly. So it seems something is overriding the model binder.

The source is located [here](https://github.com/marcusturewicz/web-api-dates) if you want to take a closer look.

Comment: Could be you are missing a IModelBinderProvider implementation?

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `return _baseBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);`? You should just return failed result if you logic failed to parse `YYYY-MM-DD` since it sounds like what you want to achieve

Comment: @JochemVanHespen As I understand it, you either apply the attribute or provide an IModelBinderProvider implementation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#implementing-a-modelbinderprovider

Comment: @Alexander I have that line as I took this from another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47449401/6939988.  Taking it out causes another 5 tests to fail. And you don't need to set the result to failed because it is set to failed as default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelbindingcontext.result?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_ModelBindingContext_Result

Comment: @marcusturewicz you are right it's either the attribute or the provider. Took a closer look ar your code and I think Alexander is right since you are failing back to a simplemodelbinder some dates will still be valid. I made you test pass with throwing an expection in case of failed and changed badrequest to internalservererror. This is not the solution. But at least you'll have an idea what's wrong

Comment: also setting `bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed()` will result in an empty (default) datetime object in your controller, that's why I opted for an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validation errors to models state so it will result into `BadRequest` later, no `_baseBinder` required

```
public class IsoDateModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            var dateTimeParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(valueAsString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTimeResult);
            if (dateTimeParsed)
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(dateTimeResult);

            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Invalid date string");
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! `bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(...)` was the missing link. And I don't need to inherit from `SimpleTypeModelBinder`. Thanks @Alexander

Comment: For future use, and to save other poor soles, I've created a library that includes an implementation for this binder https://www.nuget.org/packages/Standards.AspNetCore